# Batch adding items to Selectize.js control stalling the browser completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, batch-processing, selectize.js

i am using selectize.js to display a multiselect dropdown list witch zipcodes and cities. Its functioning well when searching and adding one item at a time, with the autocomplete search, but when im trying to add a batch of zipcodes from a multidimensional array, it totally frezzes the page, and takes more than 20 seconds to complete with insertion of a batch of 100 zip codes or so.

The following is my two add and remove functions, using data from my multidimensional array of zipcodes, with a parent region id. The events are fired via a dropdown of regions with the value of the first dimension in the region_relations array.

```
          var control = new Array();
          control.push($select[0].selectize);
          control.push($select[1].selectize);

          function addItemToselect(key_index, region){
                  var index;
                         for (index = 0; index < region_relations[region].length; ++index) {

                                control[key_index].addItem(region_relations[region][index]);


                          }

           }
           function removeItemToselect(key_index, region){
                    var index;
                         for (index = 0; index < region_relations[region].length; ++index) {

                                control[key_index].removeItem(region_relations[region][index]);

                          }
           }
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem - i thought i could maybe use jQuery to set the original  options checked and call the refreshItems() function in selectize, but it seems like selectize is actually emptying the original , and so options will only be present in this element if an item has been selected using selectize - the script itself includes a addItems() function, but it basically does the same as above, i hoped the selectize addItem had a efficient way of batch adding items, but as it seems right now, i might be out of luck, and  we are talking a max of 100 items to add or remove at a time....?

Do you have any suggestions?

My problem can be demonstrated "real life" on this page: http://onlineboligsalg.dk/soeg-bolig/ , the controls are found on the left.

thanks in advance for your help